# Samba Shares not working after reboot

Tags: 12.04, samba, lts, sharing

After a reboot of a Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.8.0-35-generic x86_64)
 LTS server, the samba shares are no longer working.

Details:

Connecting to the samba shares from a Windows server using the IP address of the server. Example \ipaddress\sharename

I am connecting with the same username and passwords on the client and server

Able to ping the linux server from the windows server. Restarted nmbd and smbd services. Checked/reset passwords for users and smbusername passwords.

System Firewall:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
3306/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
161/udp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
137/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
138/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
139/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
445/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
3306/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
161/udp                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
137/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
138/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
139/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
445/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
3306/tcp                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
3306/tcp                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
```

Samba share config:

```
[Sharename1]
    comment = sharename1
    path = /home/username1
    force user = username1
    browseable = yes
    writeable = yes
    read only = No
    create mask = 0754

[Sharename2]
    comment = sharename2
    path = /home/username2
    force user = username2
    browseable = yes
    writeable = yes
    read only = No
    create mask = 0754
```

All shares are not working but were working before the reboot.

log.smbd

```
[2014/04/10 08:28:08.606322,  0] smbd/server.c:1107(main)
standard input is not a socket, assuming -D option
[2014/04/10 15:50:21,  0] smbd/server.c:1051(main)
smbd version 3.6.3 started.
Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2011
[2014/04/10 15:50:21.293312,  0] smbd/server.c:1107(main)
standard input is not a socket, assuming -D option
```

log.nmbd

```
  This response was from IP 172.25.11.22, reporting an IP address of 172.25.11.22.
[2014/04/10 16:27:07,  0] nmbd/nmbd_namequery.c:109(query_name_response)
  query_name_response: Multiple (2) responses received for a query on subnet     172.25.69.37 for name WORKGROUP<1d>.
 This response was from IP 172.25.11.22, reporting an IP address of 172.25.11.22.
[2014/04/10 16:27:07,  0] nmbd/nmbd_namequery.c:109(query_name_response)
query_name_response: Multiple (2) responses received for a query on subnet   172.25.69.39 for name WORKGROUP<1d>.
  This response was from IP 172.25.11.22, reporting an IP address of 172.25.11.22.
[2014/04/10 16:27:07,  0] nmbd/nmbd_namequery.c:109(query_name_response)
query_name_response: Multiple (2) responses received for a query on subnet 172.25.69.116 for name WORKGROUP<1d>.
 This response was from IP 172.25.11.22, reporting an IP address of 172.25.11.22.
[2014/04/10 16:27:07,  0] nmbd/nmbd_namequery.c:109(query_name_response)
query_name_response: Multiple (2) responses received for a query on subnet 172.25.69.160 for name WORKGROUP<1d>.
 This response was from IP 172.25.11.22, reporting an IP address of 172.25.11.22.
[2014/04/10 16:27:07,  0] nmbd/nmbd_namequery.c:109(query_name_response)
 query_name_response: Multiple (2) responses received for a query on subnet 172.25.69.168 for name WORKGROUP<1d>.
 This response was from IP 172.25.11.22, reporting an IP address of 172.25.11.22.
[2014/04/10 16:27:07,  0] nmbd/nmbd_namequery.c:109(query_name_response)
 query_name_response: Multiple (2) responses received for a query on subnet 172.25.69.205 for name WORKGROUP<1d>.
  This response was from IP 172.25.11.22, reporting an IP address of 172.25.11.22.
```

Comment: Any errors in `/var/log/samba/log.smbd` or `log.nmbd`?

Comment: See edited above

Comment: The log.nmbd shows connections to multiple subnets

Comment: This is probably not your problem if you are trying to connect by IP address, but Samba uses ports 137 and 138 over UDP, not TCP.